# how to use Tinkerpop blueprints API in arangodb to get all vertices and edges

Tags: java, arangodb, tinkerpop, tinkerpop-blueprint

I have created graph and add vertices and edges using Tinkerpop api by using below code

```
ArangoDBBatchGraph arang = new ArangoDBBatchGraph("localhost", 8529, "testgraph", "testcollection", "testedgecollection");
        Vertex user = null;
        Vertex preVertex = null;
        preVertex = arang.addVertex(0);
        preVertex.setProperty("name", "edgevertex");

        long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
        for(int rec = 1; rec<=10; rec++) {

            user = arang.addVertex(rec);
            user.setProperty("name", "user"+ rec);
            user.setProperty("userid", rec);
            user.setProperty("gender", "male");
            user.setProperty("firstname", "user");
            user.setProperty("lastname", rec);
            user.setProperty("employee number", "emp0"+ rec);

            arang.addEdge(rec, user, preVertex, "edge"+ rec);
            preVertex = user;
        }

        System.out.println("write Time consumed : "+ (System.currentTimeMillis() - startTime));
```

but i want to get all the edges and vertices in the graph
I tried below code, its not working throwing exception Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException
    at com.arangodb.blueprints.batch.ArangoDBBatchGraph.getVertices(ArangoDBBatchGraph.java:277)
    at mydb.ArangodbTest.TestConnection.main(TestConnection.java:54)

```
startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
        Iterable<Vertex>  iter = arang.getVertices();
        List<Vertex> list = new ArrayList<Vertex>();
        if(iter != null) {
            for(final Vertex vert : iter) {
                list.add(vert);
            }
        }
        Iterable<Edge>  iterEdge = arang.getEdges();
        List<Edge> listEdge = new ArrayList<Edge>();
        if(iter != null) {
            for(Edge edge : iterEdge) {
                listEdge.add(edge);
            }
        }

        System.out.println("Read vertices list: "+ list.size() + ", Edges List: "+listEdge+ "; Time consumed : "+ (System.currentTimeMillis() - startTime));
```

Please help to get all edges and vertices using tinkerpop api from arangodb

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

`ArangoDBBatchGraph` does not support the methods `getVertices()` and `getEdges()`. You have to use `ArangoDBGraph` instead of `ArangoDBBatchGraph`.

Apart from this your code should work.